# Symfony check form field exist inside controller

Tags: forms, symfony

Is there a way to check if a form field exist inside a controller?

I have a few submit buttons but depending on the data in the object the associated one will be shown and created.

FormType.php

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    /** @var ObjectInfo $tab */
    $tab = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (some condition) {
        //No Value has been set or NULL
        $form->add('submit_second', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'submit',
        ))
    }
```

controller.php

```
 if ($overviewForm->get('submit_second')->isClicked()) {
     // do something
 }
```

I have also tried

```
if (
    !is_null($overviewForm->get('submit_second')) && 
    $overviewForm->get('submit_second')->isClicked()
) {
```

on submit I get

Error

```
Child "submit_second" does not exist.
```

Comment: Just guessing: if ($overviewForm->has('submit_second')) {...}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `$form->has('field')` (suggested by `@jahller`) does work in Symfony 6.3 (maybe also in older versions).

Comment: Just wanted to add the reference documentation here.
https://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_has

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `try catch`. I am not actually sure when the OutOfBounds exception was introduced. But I am using this in 3.4

```
try {
    $field = $form->get('nonExistantChild');
    // Then you know the field exists
} catch (Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\OutOfBoundsException $e) {
    // Field doesn't exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work on data instead since most of the time you need it anyway.

```
if (!array_key_exists('nonExistantChild', $data = $event->getData())) { 
    // No need to do anything then
    return; 
}

// Can now do something with $data then
```